# I am having trouble determining if I should use a combination of a permutation in the following example

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

Three balls are drawn from a bag with 2 white and 3 black balls. 
There are 20 outcomes (sequences) in S (I think they are telling us this to say that order is important).

What is the probability that the second ball is white?

Let $F$ be the event that the first ball is white.

Let $S$ be the event that the second ball is white.
$$ P(S) = P(S|F)\times P(F) + P(S|F^c)\times P(F^c) = \frac{1}{4}\times \frac{2} {5} + \frac{2}{4} \times \frac{3}{5} = \frac{2}{5}$$

I don't understand how they get the $P(S|F)$ and the $P(S|F^c)$

My first successful attempt was to solve for $P(S|F) = \frac{P(S\cap F)}{P(F)} = \frac{2/20}{2/5} = 1/4$

However, I'm trying to solve it using permutations or combinations because it would be more difficult to guess the probability if the number of outcomes wasn't given. Since order is important, I am leaning towards thinking that I could do it with a permutation, but it works with combinations as well.So since one white ball was already removed:

$$\frac{\dbinom{1}{1}}{\dbinom{4}{1}} = \frac{1}{4}$$

$$\frac{_1P_1}{_4P_1} = \frac{1}{4}$$

Comment: Yes you're right it was 3, I corrected it.

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking too much in terms of formulas. You saw, for example, that given the first is white, the probability the second is white is $1/4$, for there are $4$ balls left of which only one is white.Similarly, given the first is black, the probability the second is white is $2/4$, since there are $2$ whites left.

Comment: Oh, wow you're right. I missed that entirely. It seems so obvious now Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome.